Rotating a 3d prism in TikZ
I'm trying to recreate this image without color: 
 
My code so far:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate around y=127]
    \draw (0,9,8) -- (6,9,0) -- (0,9,0) -- (0,9,8) -- (0,0,8) -- (0,0,0) -- (6,0,0) -- (6,9,0);
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,9,0);
    \draw[dashed,dash pattern={on 20pt off 10pt}] (0,0,8) -- (6,0,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I want to rotate the prism to make it look more to scale.

You can use tikz-3dplot to draw this, and then rotate the main coordinate frame as you like. If you want to orient it so that the z-axis is not upright, then you can use \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{Z}{Y}{Z}.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130} % change these to alter the perspective
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
    \draw[->] (-10,0,0) -- (10,0,0) node[below right]{$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-10,0) -- (0,10,0) node[below left]{$y$};
    \draw[->] (0,0,-10) -- (0,0,10) node[above]{$z$};

    % I switched the y and z coords, since z is upright in tikz-3
    \draw (0,8,9) -- (6,0,9) -- (0,0,9) -- (0,8,9) -- (0,8,0) -- (0,0,0) -- (6,0,0) -- (6,0,9);
    \draw (0,0,0) -- (0,0,9);
    \draw[dashed,dash pattern={on 20pt off 10pt}] (0,8,0) -- (6,0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


